# PowerShell duplicate about_ Topics that I cannot access

Tags: powershell, console

In looking at `help about_*` I find that I have a number of Topics that are listed in duplicate, and these Topics can never be viewed, so for example `help about_Checkpoint-Workflow` fails to open the Topic.

Do people know a fix for this as it is quite frustrating?

```
about_ActivityCommonParameters    
about_ActivityCommonParameters    

about_Checkpoint-Workflow         
about_Checkpoint-Workflow         

about_ForEach-Parallel            
about_ForEach-Parallel            

about_InlineScript                
about_InlineScript                

about_Parallel                    
about_Parallel                    

about_Scheduled_Jobs              
about_Scheduled_Jobs              

about_Scheduled_Jobs_Advanced     
about_Scheduled_Jobs_Advanced     

about_Scheduled_Jobs_Basics       
about_Scheduled_Jobs_Basics       

about_Scheduled_Jobs_Troublesh... 
about_Scheduled_Jobs_Troublesh... 

about_Sequence                    
about_Sequence                    

about_Suspend-Workflow            
about_Suspend-Workflow            

about_WorkflowCommonParameters    
about_WorkflowCommonParameters    

about_Workflows                   
about_Workflows
```

Comment: there were glitches with the help updates and with some module help files ... that resulted in dupe files OR in files with different extensions. the fix is to find the location of each file and delete or move the older version.

Comment: The linked issue hopefully answers your question.

Comment: I got your gist to find the files and delete the duplicate thanks, works well, have removed the dups. Wow, quite a nasty bug that Microsoft have there. Not a bug in the language itself, but they really should prevent that from happening ...